# Radare2: how to change operand from integer value to (flag + offset) in disassembly output?

Tags: radare2

*this is Easy_ELF from Reversing.Kr*

Right now R2 displays absolute address for a character inside of a string:

```
  [0x08048454]> pdf
  ...
  0x08048454      0fb60521a004.  movzx eax, byte [0x804a021]
```

I already made a flag for global buffer

```
 f glob.passwordBuf 16 @ 0x0804a020
```

how to apply offset from it to make R2 to display something like

```
 0x08048454      0fb60521a004.  movzx eax, byte [glob.passwordBuf + 1]
```

? I.e. I want disassembler to use  what `fd 0x804a021` returns (which is `glob.passwordBuf + 1`)

I tried to reanalyze the function, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an enhancement to be done on asm.relsub see https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/5956

I have created an issue on the radare2 repository, feel free to do similar next time or to come by the IRC or the Telegram channel.